# Cannot get wireless interface to work

Tags: debian, wifi, kernel-modules, lmde

I cannot get my WiFi adapter to work on LMDE2 (fresh install with btrfs).

```
# lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f68fe000-f68fffff
```

I have tried using `modprobe` according to some instructions on the debian site after also following the instructions for installing the module with `apt`:

```
# modprobe -r iwlwifi; modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/modules.dep.bin'
```

The interface doesn't show as up when I do `ifconfig -a` or in network-manager.

EDIT 1: `/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic` does not exist. I've just installed all the kernel-related updates.

Comment: Please, post link to documentation which gives instructions to you about this topic. Also, strange steps: `modprobe -r ...` (remove module) then `modprobe ...`(trying to load module). Why you need to do this? Maybe you build wifi module by himself? If it's true, you should run `insmod /path/to/module` or place module to kernel module directory and execute `depmod`. Further, your call of `modprobe module` will be executed.

Comment: Can you add the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` . The `linux-image-3.16.0-5-amd64` is available , you can install it then reboot and try to load the driver.